# Poetry completion is not working in macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, zsh, autocomplete

On a pristine macOS I followed the steps listed [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/#enable-tab-completion-for-bash-fish-or-zsh) ending with a `.zshrc` file like this:

```
export PATH="/Users/canciobello/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH"

fpath+=~/.zfunc
compinit
```

The `zsh` shell is complaining about the *compinit* line, so I try to remove it, but either way, it didn't works.

Comment: I'm not sure what most of the operations are on that page are doing, but `compinit` is an autoload function. It needs to be invoked with the line `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` in `~/.zshrc`'.

Comment: @Gairfowl Thank you, that was the issue.